# How to interpret error in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I totally don't understand what I am doing with ColdFusion, but was forced to work on it. Can someone tell me what this error means? Please explain specifically. Thank you.

**Code:**

```
<h1> Dear <cfif><cfoutput>#session.member.nmFirst# #session.member.nmLast#</cfoutput><cfelse>Student</cfelse></cfif>,</h1>
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 3 at column 19.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

>

The CFML compiler was processing:
A cfif tag beginning on line 3, column 15.

Resources:

Enable Robust Exception Information to provide greater detail about the source of errors. In the Administrator, click Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings, and select the Robust Exception Information option.
Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.

Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Remote Address      xxxxxx
Referrer    http://www.xxxx.com/index.cfm/page/application-step-final
Date/Time       06-Feb-15 05:21 PM
```

Comment: It means that on line 3, there was a coldfusion syntax error. Most likely an incorrect tag or incorrect usage of `#`. It is most likely contained within the cfif tag.

Comment: Is it in the page Referrer?

Comment: it was on the page that was being viewed when the error occured, or in a file being included on that page.

Comment: <h1>
 Dear <cfif><cfoutput>#session.member.nmFirst# #session.member.nmLast#</cfoutput><cfelse>Student</cfelse></cfif>,</h1> . Is this a good syntax?

Comment: why is your cfif empty?

Comment: No, it's  missing a condition for the `<cfif>`

Comment: If you're needing to test something and want the cfif to always pass, you can just say `<cfif 1 eq 1>`, but you can't just remove the condition entirely. You can use an or statement so you don't have to delete the condition already there `<cfif 1 eq 1 or myothercondition eq someothervalue>`

Comment: @user1874435 always include your code *in your question*, not as a comment.

Comment: Voting to close as this is just a "can you put a second set of eyes on this" sort of question.

Comment: @cfqueryparam why `1 eq 1`? why not just `true` ?

Comment: @AdamCameron That too, I was just giving stating an actual coditon, though very brief.

Answer (score 1):

Just so this question doesn't hang around being open, I'll answer it properly, rather than relying on the answer in the comments. This is duplicated from there.

```
<h1> Dear <cfif><cfoutput>#session.member.nmFirst# #session.member.nmLast#</cfoutput><cfelse>Student</cfelse></cfif>,</h1>
```

You don't have a condition in your `<cfif>`.

Comment: also shouldn't have the closing `</cfelse>`

Comment: Oh bloody hell, yeah. Didn't notice that!